# 12.10 running 10.4 under vserver

Tags: system-installation

I want to do some testing with bigbluebutton and the installation documentation refers to Jaunty 9.04 or Lucid 10.04. I'm running 12.10 and don't want to use a VM. Can I install 10.04 as a vserver client and run BBB in it?

Will there be any problems with library or binary incompatibilities?

Comment: I'd like to see an answer to this, but I reckon it wouldn't work since the kernel versions differ and probably this will be a blocker. Unless you use full virtualization, I don't think it'll work. +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible.
Quoting from [help.ubuntu.com > What are VServers > Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VServer#Installation_.28u32.29):

> **Create a new guest**
>
> ```
> /etc/vservers/newvserver-vars (man newvserver(1) for options):
>
> DIST='dapper'
> MIRROR="http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"
> ```
>
> This command creates a new Ubuntu Dapper image. You can change
>   "dapper" to "edgy" or whatever you want above. **You can run virtually
>   any Linux distribution as a guest** (for instance, Gentoo).

Bigbluebutton is based on Apache Tomcat, mySQL and several libraries, I don't see too many incompability problems here. However, I didn't verify all myself.

**EDIT:** However, using a virtual machine should be the easier & quicker way - as there is at least one [preconfigured VMWare image with a BBB system](http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/BigBlueButtonVM#Requirements).

Comment: Isn't `dapper` and `edgy` a bit outdated w.r.t. the question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll give it a go and see how I get on. Do you have any idea what the performance overhead of the VM would be?